# Google sign is not working when debugging in another machine

Tags: android, firebase, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I have the google sign in working when I debug with my mac. But when I do it on another mac, Google sign-in is not authenticating. I have added the SHA1 of both laptops in FireBase.

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data).isSuccess();
```

is returning False always when I run on other machines.
I am getting this error, when I try to print
     Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data).getStatus();

```
Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}
```

Anyone been in similar situation?

Comment: Try adding your google-service.json file in app folder in your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some conditions you have to check,

**First --** Check `google-services.json` is added in your project or not.

**Second --** If you have already added `SHA-1` to firebase console. Then cross-check `SHA-1` of your machine at firebase console is correct or not.

**Third --** If you are using new machine. Then check have you added `SHA-1 Fingerprint` of your another machine in your project on `firebase console` or not.

You have to add `SHA-1` of your every machine you are working with that project. Because `SHA-1` helps `Firebase Console` to identify your machine that is registered on it. And if `SHA-1` not present on `Firebase Console` then it shows `DEVELOPER_ERROR`.